# Failed to execute action, message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (TypeError) could not coerce Integer to class java.lang.String"

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

[ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (TypeError) could not coerce Integer to class java.lang.String"

Comment: my conf file input {
  file {
    path => "C:/elk/spring-boot-elk.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    user => kibana_test_user
    password => 123456
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  
}

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, the Logstash can't cast String to Integer value.
If you wrote the real password, you need to surround it with apostrophes like:
password => "123456"